# HTML String in Onclick Event

Tags: php, html, string, onclick

```
<?php

echo '<input name="checkbox" value="student" type="checkbox" onclick=change(this, "type"); />';

?>
```

This isn't working. I keep getting in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

How do I input a string as a parameter for an onclick event?

```
<script>
        function change(cb, year) {
            var value = cb.value;
            var type = cb.checked;
            var yr = year;

            $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url:"process.php",
                data: { 'data':value, 'type':type, 'yr':yr, },
                success:function(result) {
                    console.log("works" + result);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not wrapped your `onChange` function in double quotes :

```
echo '<input name="checkbox" value="student" type="checkbox" onclick="change(this, \'type\');" />';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/maine_journal/redesign/cp/index.php on line 78

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I have updated my javascript for you to take a look at.

Comment: @user3537973 : check again.